# Почему Live SASS compiler выводит style.css и style.min.css в папку sass? Хотя в настройках четко указано папка css

Tags: html, css, sass

Получается у меня генерируется и в папку css и в папку sass. Что очень странно( А я хочу токо в одну папку.
Настройка: (по-моему все правильно)

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": true,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "compressed",
            "extensionName": ".min.css",
            "savePath": "~/../css/"
        }
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [
        "**/node_modules/**",
        ".vscode/**"
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions"
    ],
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос.

1. Так как у меня в проекте папка sass находится на одном уровне с папкой css, то необходимо в пути вывода файла писать это:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "compressed",
            "extensionName": ".min.css",
            "savePath": "/css/"
        }
    ],
```

2. (для другого случая) - если же в вашем проекте сначала идут папки src и dist, то в таком случае надо писать папку src:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "compressed",
            "extensionName": ".min.css",
            "savePath": "/src/css/"
        }
    ],
```

Возможно знатоки увидят в этом ответе ошибку. Это возможно, потому что, пока я новичок и такие ошибки обыденность) Но этот метод рабочий)